# Select next record with the same id

Tags: mysql, sql, duplicates

I have a sample table for answers with the following rows. The id could be duplicate as it's joined with questions table based on the id (i.e a question could have multiple answers)

```
answers.id | answers.username | answer | date
   1       |       mikha      | you    | 2013-01-01 00:00:00   
   1       |     maricela     | really | 2013-01-01 00:00:00 
   1       |        guy       | rock   | 2013-01-01 00:00:00
```

Is there a query I can use to select all rows after the answer by "maricela"?

Something similar to:

```
SELECT * FROM answers WHERE id = 1 AND answers.username > 'maricela'
```

But the above will return 0 rows as doing it like above will select alphabetically and guy alphabetically is before maricela.

Is there any method to select row after row with value(s)? Row after `ID=1` and `USERNAME=mariclea`?

Comment: Do you mean you want to select rows which are physically stored in the table after the one you mention? Is there a primary key on answers?

Comment: Rows in a relational database do not have any implicit order. So you need to have a column that tells us why 'guy' in your example is "after" 'maricela', when the id and date columns are the same value. If you don't have such a column then you can't reliably say whether 'guy' is before or after 'maricela'.

Comment: There id a primary key `PRIMARY KEY  ('id','username')` as there is unique combination of id and username as the the a user can answer a question only once. So mikha can't answer ID 1 two times but ID 1 could be answered by mikha, maricela, and guy but they can't give more than one answer...thanks @IanGregory

Comment: Unfortunately the primary key on id and username doesn't tell us anything about the order in which the answers were provided, so you will need to adopt something like @John Farrelly's suggestion to add another column which you can use to order the answers by.

Comment: Is there a way to get the date to be so accurate that it would be nearly impossible for 2 answers to hit the database at the same exact time?

Comment: @MichaelSamuel - unfortunately "nearly" isn't enough if you expect always to get correct results. I really think you would be better served by having an autoincrementing primary key - they are guaranteed to be always unique, and in a single instance database they will be in the order of insertion of records (though not necessarily in the order in which they are committed).

Answer (score 2):

I would **strongly** suggest you add a unique id in your answers table, and have a new column that is used to join to the questions table:

```
question_id |  id | username | answer | date
    1       |   1 | mikha    | you    | 2013-01-01 00:00:00   
    1       |   2 | maricela | really | 2013-01-01 00:00:00 
    1       |   3 | guy      | rock   | 2013-01-01 00:00:00
```

Then you could use:

```
SELECT * FROM answers WHERE id > (
    SELECT id FROM answer WHERE username = 'maricela' and question_id = 1
)
```

Answer (score 0):

something popped up in my mind: if your concept of "after" is related to time (i.e. answers inserted after "maricela") then you can consider adding DATE/TIME column for the answers table. This way you would make sure that some answers are given later than others

Comment: oh I just noticed there is already date column.. well you can add also the hour:min:sec.millisec part

Comment: Indeed, or an autoincrementing sequence number that for a single database instance will provide the same ordering (apart from out-of-order commits).

Answer (score 0):

This will simply do,

```
SELECT b.* FROM table1 b WHERE b.id> 
(SELECT a.id FROM table1 a WHERE a.username='maricela'
and a.answer_id=1)
```

[**Live SQL Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2e17f/7)

Comment: This is giving me a syntax error `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'EXISTS (SELECT a.username FROM answers a WHERE a.username=b.username and a.user' at line 1` Also what about if 'maricela` is answering other IDs? I need to be specific about `ID =1` thanks :)

Comment: try now. If it shows error then post your code in this comment window.

Comment: `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'EXISTS (SELECT a.username FROM answers a WHERE a.username=b.username and a.usern' at line 1`

Comment: @MichaelSamuel this query is syntax vise correct. I might have used column names wrongly. Can you check if all the column names are correct.. Meanwhile I will do live demo. Wait..

Comment: @Mari 1. The query you have suggested does not have any order by clause. 2. Rows in a table in a relational database are unordered. 3. There is currently no suitable column in the table that can be used for ordering. 1+2+3 implies that there is nothing you can do without the addition of a suitable ordering column to the table :(

Comment: @MichaelSamuel edited my answer. You can see the live demo and change only column names as per your table structure.

Comment: hey @Mari your query simply displays all the rows while i need to select rows inserted after maricela which should be just guy's row only